# Which statistical test should I use in my data?

Tags: r

I am currently doing a study about the preference of humpback whales singing during night in the subarctic waters.

I have two variables in my data Existenceofsong (positive or negative detection; song and no song) and for the correspondent time each daylight regime (light, twilight or dark).

I can send my data if you want to see it.

I would be very grateful if someone could give some tips with how should I have test my data and how to convert my variable so I can test them.

Thank you in advange for your attention.